# Will Netty be a good choice for a Server multiplexor implementation?

Tags: netty

Server would typically do the following:

-Netty server receive clientX  bind on tcp port.(all very Simple text protocol).

-Netty receive auth request.

-Netty  will now create a channel group called clientX - inside this channel group it will create 4 tcp connections (one to each external server) perform auth's on servers for user and send back 1 ACK to clientX.

-Receive next request from clientX it will route/relay message to connection1 within clientX's channel group.

-Receive next message and route/relay request to connection2 within clientX's channel group.

-Receive logout request, disconnect channel group, which in turn will disconnect all connections inside clientX's channel group.

-Messages received from any of the external servers must be routed/relayed back to clientx (mux)

Answer (score 2):

Such things can be done with netty.

I think a good starting point is the proxy example:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy

---

I've modified the proxy example to implement the server as described above.
design: with netty-3.5.3

Clients<->|(s-soc)-MUX_NIO_server-(c-socks) |<->server1(lb)

```
                                        |<->server2
                                        |<->server3
                                        |<->server4
```

pipeline=>framedecoder-->stringdecoder-->clienthandler-->framedecoder-->stringdecoder-->serverHandler--|

It runs 100% until it reach +/- 100 tps, then the same message from the client gets send to the server over and over again,looks like a deadlock situation.

In both handlers my  channelInterestChanged events looks like this:

//channelInterestChanged
 synchronized (trafficLock) {

```
  if (e.getChannel().isWritable()) {

        inboundChannel.setReadable(true);

          if (inboundChannel != null) {

             inboundChannel.setReadable(true);
         }

  }
```

}

in both handlers message rx i write like this:

synchronized (trafficLock) {

```
final ChannelFutureListener writeListener =
                new ChannelFutureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(final ChannelFuture future)
                            throws Exception {
                        if (Consts.DEBUG_ENABLED) {
                            log.debug("Finished Writing message);
                        }
                    }
                };

        /* if channel is write */
        if (inboundChannel.isWritable()) {
                inboundChannel.write(bufferMsg).addListener(writeListener);
        }
        // If inboundChannel is saturated, do not read until notified in
         if (!inboundChannel.isWritable()) {
            e.getChannel().setReadable(false);
        }
```

}

Any idea what could be wrong and where to look to fix this?Thanks

Comment: Think this also looks like good example? http://www.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/xref/index.html